# Get a value and do the maths based on that value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing an odds comparison site, What I'd like to do is get the value i.e 13/2 and do the maths as in 13 Divided 2 = 6.5

Then I'd like to tag the 6.5 on as a data-odds-decimal value on a button.

My jQuery is looping each class, But not doing the necessary maths.

My HTML code is as follows :

```
<button class="odds-btn" data-odds-fractional="13/2">13/2</button>
<button class="odds-btn" data-odds-fractional="2/5">2/5</button>
<button class="odds-btn" data-odds-fractional="1/2">1/2</button>
```

So for each data-odds-fractional I need to do the maths of 13/2, 2/5, 1/2 to then return the decimal value.

My current jQuery is as follows...

```
$('.odds-btn').each(function()
    {
        // Get The Decimal Value...
        var odds_decimal = $(this).attr('data-odds-fractional');

        // Add The Fractional Value as a new attr...
        var odds_fractional = odds_decimal;
        $(this).attr('data-odds-decimal', odds_fractional);
    })
```

The data-odds-decimal is just coming back as the fractional value, Can I get jQuery to force do the maths or any other way?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make jQuery do a calculation like that, it will only do simple parsing when reading the data values.

Split the string and do the calculation:

```
var parts = odds_decimal.split('/');
var odds_fractional = parseInt(parts[0], 10) / parseInt(parts[1], 10);
```

Comment: Excellent, Thank you for that. Helped me out a great deal